# Linux packages install via Terminal error (unmet dependencies)

Tags: command-line, dependencies, qt

I tried to install a new Point Cloud Library but got this error
[install error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5eN9.png)

I also tried to install them separately with:

```
# sudo apt install libboost-all-dev libvtk6-dev libvtk6-qt-dev
```

just got me more missing packages
[separat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cutx.png)

also tried

```
# sudo apt update

# sudo apt upgrade
```

any tips?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Please don't provide pictures of text (we cannot copy & paste missing packages from a picture to look up why you aren't seeing them), let alone we don't know your release which is also needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for the bad post :/ i was unable to fix it but i just set up a new one.. sry and thanks <3